# The output Wordcloud does not update in Shiny

Tags: rstudio, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to build a Shiny app with a reactive word cloud. As of right now, it is only generating a static word cloud that does not change when I select a different input.

These are the packages I am using:

```
library(shiny)
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(SnowballC)
library(memoise)
```

ui.R

```
ui <- fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("Word Cloud"), sidebarLayout(

# Sidebar with a slider and selection inputs
sidebarPanel(
selectInput("selection", "Choose an agency:", choices = Agencies),
actionButton("update", "Change"),
hr(),
sliderInput("freq",
"Minimum Frequency:",
min = 1,  max = 50, value = 15),
sliderInput("max", "Maximum Number of Words:", min = 1,  max = 300,  value = 100)),

# Show Word Cloud
mainPanel(
plotOutput("plot"))))
```

server.R

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Define a reactive expression for the document term matrix
  terms <- reactive({
    input$update
    # ...but not for anything else

    Agencies <<- list("NASA" = "NASA", "DOD" = "DOD")

    getTermMatrix <- function(Agency) {
      if(!(Agency %in% Agencies))
        stop("Unknown Agency")

      PropCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(x$Proposal.Title))
      PropCorpus <- tm_map(PropCorpus, PlainTextDocument)
      myCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(PropCorpus))
      myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
      myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
      myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
      myDTM = TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus, control = list(minWordLength = 1))
      m = as.matrix(myDTM)
      sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE)
    }

       getTermMatrix(input$selection)
  })

  # Make the wordcloud drawing predictable during a session
  wordcloud_rep <- repeatable(wordcloud)

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    v <- terms()
    wordcloud_rep(names(v), v, scale=c(4,0.5),
                  min.freq = input$freq, max.words=input$max,
                  colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
  })
}
```

My data is essentially two columns one with the Agency names and one with a description of different contracts.

Comment: I think you are missing some code here. in "getTermMatrix" you refer to variables "x" and "PlainTextDocument" that are nowhere defined here. I suspect they are defined by you locally. Basically the information you are making the word cloud from is not defined here. You probably have them defined locally which is why things are not changing when you run your shiny program.

Comment: Or maybe there is another chunk that you have not shown us...

Comment: I don't see where input$selection gets used to actually get the the TDM.  Your function only calls on the variable in your if statement but is silent on the corpus creation.  So I think it just creates a single corpus without any specification from your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help! I finally figured it out, so I wanted to share my final code.

First load data and packages:

```
 contract_data_df <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
contract_data_df$Agency <- as.factor(contract_data_df$Agency)
attach(contract_data_df)
library(shiny)
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(SnowballC)
library(memoise)
```

In my dataset I have two columns: Agency (Factors) and Proposal.Title (string). The purpose of this word cloud was to visualize the words most prominent in the proposal titles associated with multiple federal agencies.

Setting up the user interface (UI):

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Word Cloud"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      #selectInput("selection", "Choose an agency:", choices = list("DOD"="DOD", "NASA"="NASA")),
      selectInput("selection", "Choose an agency:", choices = Agency, selected = 1),
      actionButton("update", "Change"),
      hr(),
      sliderInput("freq",
                  "Minimum Frequency:",
                  min = 1,  max = 50, value = 15),
      sliderInput("max", "Maximum Number of Words:", min = 1,  max = 300,  value = 100)),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot"))))
```

Set up the server:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

terms <- reactive({
input$update
agencies <<- list("DOD"="DOD", "NASA"="NASA")
getCorpusMatrix <- function(agency){
text <- subset(contract_data_df, contract_data_df$Agency == input$selection)
contract_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text$Proposal.Title))
contract_corpus <- tm_map(contract_corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
contract_corpus <- tm_map(contract_corpus, removePunctuation)
contract_corpus <- tm_map(contract_corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
contract_corpus <- tm_map(contract_corpus, stripWhitespace)
contract_corpus <- tm_map(contract_corpus, stemDocument)


contract_dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(contract_corpus)
contract_dtm_df <- data.frame(as.matrix(contract_dtm))
sort(rowSums(contract_dtm_df), decreasing = TRUE)
}

getCorpusMatrix(input$update)
})

wordcloud_rep <- repeatable(wordcloud)
output$plot <- renderPlot({
v <- terms()
wordcloud_rep(names(v), v, scale=c(4,0.5),
min.freq = input$freq, max.words=input$max,
colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
})
}
```

Finally, launch the app:

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```